# get; set; in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a class that replaces the `get` and `set` functions:

```
template <class T, class U = T, class V = T>
class GetSet
{
public:
    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, T>::value && std::is_same<V, T>::value>>
    inline GetSet() { getf = getNormal; setf = setNormal; };
    inline GetSet(U (*getf)(T), T (*setf)(V)) { this->getf = getf; this->setf = setf; };

    inline operator U() { return getf(value); };
    inline U operator () () { return getf(value); };
    inline GetSet<T>& operator = (V v) { value = setf(v); return *this; };

    // only for tuples
    template <int N>
    inline auto get() { static_assert(N < std::tuple_size<T>::value, "Index out of bounds"); return std::get<N>(getf(value)); };
    template <int N, class W>
    inline GetSet<T>& set(W w) { static_assert(N < std::tuple_size<T>::value, "Index out of bounds"); auto a = getf(value); std::get<N>(a) = w; value = setf(a); return *this; };
private:
    inline static T getNormal(T t) { return t; };
    inline static T setNormal(T t) { return t; };

    U (*getf)(T t);
    T (*setf)(V v);
    T value;
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
utils::GetSet<std::tuple<int, int>> getSet
    (
        [](std::tuple<int, int> t)
        {
            auto[x, y] = t;
            return std::tuple(x - 1, y - 1);
        },
        [](std::tuple<int, int> t)
        {
            auto[x, y] = t;
            return std::tuple(x - 1, y - 1);
        }
        );

getSet = { 1, 2 };
auto[i, j] = getSet(); // in this example the parentheses are required, because of the auto keyword
getSet.set<0>(8);
auto r = getSet.get<0>();
// r = 6
```

Or a very simple example:

```
utils::GetSet<int> simple;
simple = 1;
int r2 = simple;
```

The `U` and `V` templates are used in case you want to have `get`/`set` functions with different parameters rather than just the standard type that's stored in the class. The main issue I'm aware of is that it's not possible to have a public get and a private set for example.